# How can I invert the order of items in a golang map?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and I'd like to invert the order of appearance of  pairs in a map like this so that the last pair comes first:

```
mapA := map[string]int {
    "cat": 5,
    "dog": 2,
    "fish": 3 ,
}


fmt.Println(mapA)


map[cat:5 dog:2 fish:3]
```

The resulting map should be like:

```
map[fish:3 dog:2 cat:5]
```

It can be a new mapB with the same items but iverted order.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't, because there is no order to begin with in a map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Map types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> A map is an unordered group of elements.
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed
>   to be the same from one iteration to the next.

---

You can't. A Go map is not ordered. A Go map is a hash map (hash table).

To get the map contents in order (or reverse order), read the map contents into a slice and sort it.

---

> [Hash table - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)
>
> A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an array of
>   buckets or slots, from which the desired value can be found.
>
> Drawbacks
>
> The entries stored in a hash table can be enumerated efficiently (at
>   constant cost per entry), but only in some pseudo-random order.
>   Therefore, there is no efficient way to locate an entry whose key is
>   nearest to a given key. Listing all n entries in some specific order
>   generally requires a separate sorting step, whose cost is proportional
>   to log(n) per entry.

Comment: What about creating a new map with inverse order of items?

Comment: @Babr Maps are unordered. Creating a new map will result in yet another unordered map.

Comment: The point peter is trying to make is there is no "order" of a map. If you wanted some sort of list with indexes you want to use a slice: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7